# Style first level of menu only

Tags: css, menu, navigation, descendant

To style the first level of a menu i would think this code would work:

http://jsfiddle.net/2g36L/1/

Could someone please point out where I'm going wrong, thanks.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to add a class to the first level `li` elements?

Comment: It's called inheritance. CSS is very good at it.

Comment: I just updated the example, and yes i'm trying the first level of li but doesn't seem to work, can u have a play with the code, thanks.

Comment: It works as supposed. If you want to select only second menu try for selector `li > ul`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does, but since you've given no other color to the other elements they inherit the color you gave the top `<ul>` element. If you give the other `<ul>` a color, it works fine.

**[jsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2g36L/2/)**

Comment: +1 - Your solution is fine, but I would do it like this: `ul {}` for the first level and `ul > li > ul {}` for the second level. As in your style the second level gets the default style for all other `ul`s on the page. And also the hierarchy gets a little clearer. And yes, it's also in my example the case that the first level `ul` gets the default `ul`, but maybe this is useful or you could add a `div > […]` to both if applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Color is an inherited CSS trait, so even though you are declaring it only for the immediate UL beneath the div, it is being inherited by the nested elements.